# Python2.7 contextlib.ExitStack equivalent

Tags: python-2.7, mocking, contextmanager

To programmatically combine context managers I use the following code:

== helpers.py ==

```
from contextlib import nested
import mock

def multiple_patch(obj_to_be_patch, *methods):
    return nested(
        *[mock.patch.object(obj_to_be_patch, method) for method in methods]
    )
```

== tests.py ==

```
def test_foo(self):
    with helpers.multiple_patch(Foo, "method1", "method2", "method3",    "method3") as mocks:
         mock_method1 = mocks[0]
         ....
         # asserts on mocks
```

Because I'm stuck with this version of python I can't use contextlib.ExitStack and contextlib.nested is deprecated.

Thanks

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Check out [`contextlib2.ExitStack`](https://contextlib2.readthedocs.io/en/stable/#contextlib2.ExitStack), a backport of Python3's `contextlib.ExitStack`.

Comment: Historical trivia: technically the PyPI version came first (to work out the API details), and then it was forward ported from there into the Python 3 standard library. See https://bugs.python.org/issue13585#msg159754 for more info.

Comment: @ncoghlan Thanks for the correction and for all your design work to make `ExitStack` so effective.